# Running python script with sudo returns "sudo: script.py: command not found"

Tags: sudo, executable

I can run `script.py` without sudo successfully, but I am getting "sudo: script.py: command not found" when running `sudo script.py`. What I need to do to be able to run `sudo script.py`?

Comment: Where is `script.py`? Is it in a directory that's in your `PATH`? Or is it in the current directory?

Comment: It is in current directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `./` like this:

```
sudo ./script.py
```

The above is assuming the `script.py` file is in your current working directory. The `.` means "this directory", so `./script.py` refers to "`script.py` in the current directory".

Comment: Oh, it was so simple... thanks! Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Why would you assume the script is in the current directory? More importantly, please explain what the `./` is, since this would only work in the specific case where the script is in `./`, so will fail if the OP tries `sudo ./script.py` from any other directory.

Comment: @terdon thanks, I edited a bit. The reason I assumed it was in the current working directory is the filename `script.py` that to me sounded like someone was playing around with a script that was just written and not installed anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

In order to call an executable by name like that, it needs to be in one of the directories stored in the special variable `$PATH`. That PATH is different for your regular user and for `sudo`:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

~$ sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Presumably, since the script is in your current directory, you are in a directory that is included in the PATH of your regular user, but not in the PATH of `sudo`. So you need to call the script with its full or relative path:

```
## If it is in _this_ directory, use ./
sudo ./script.py

## Alternatively, use the full path:
sudo /home/terdon/myscripts/script.py

## or a relative path. If you're in /home/terdon/foo, use:
sudo ../myscripts/script.py
```